# how to auto login user

Tags: asp.net, login-control

here is what i am  trying to do:

1. user logs in and check rember me.
2. user then closes the site.
3. next time the user visits the sites he is auto logged in withoutre-entring his user or password

thanks

*using asp.net 3.5. using forms authentication*

Comment: Are you using forms authentication ?

Comment: @Bala R - yes i am using forms authentication

Comment: FYI - The remember me feature isn't an automatic re-login, its a cookie with a long expiration date.  So you're still logged in.

Comment: You should get this automatically using the standard authentication mechanism provided by ASP.Net. It will set a cookie if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are calling [`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx), you can set the second parameter to true to make the cookie persist for a very long time.

Comment: i tried this but it didn't work for me `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(mainLogin.UserName, true);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(mainLogin.Password, true);
`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your authentication model, I have a manual authentication process, by that i mean i Have a site whos entire authentication model has been coded from the ground up to suite the website. 
No built in .net is used.

We hold an auto login feature in our cookie. The way this is done is by adding the login username and password to the cookie, but all key names and values in the cookie are encrypted with triple des encryption. So in the unlikely event the cookie is decrypted, they then face a triple des encryption to get the user credentials.

We have a handler that checks if the user is logged in on each request, various flags in the session are set to signify whats happening. eg you first land on the site, the handler checks for cookie support, if not provided a flag in the session signifies client doesnt support cookies and no further attempts are made. If it does support cookies the cookie is read, and if auto login is checked the credentials from the cookie are used to login.

It is easier to use the built in .net authentication model, but for ultimate control, DIY.